# Como usar @SuperBuilder dentro de una clase que se extiende a otra

Tags: java, lombok

Me encuentro realizando una clase con la notación @SuperBuilder de lombok y esta clase se extiende a una clase genérica:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class GenericResponse {

   private int codigo;
   private String descripcion;

}

@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends GenericResponse {

   private Long id;
   private String nombre;

   public static Child crear(ChildDto childDto){
    return Child.builder()
            .id(childDto.getId())
            .nombre(childDto.getNombre())
            .codigo(0)
            .descripcion("success")
            .build();
   }
}
```

Mi intención es utilizar el builder() dentro del método crear(ChildDto childDto), pero SonarLint me entrega el siguiente Warning:

```
Use static access with "GenericResponse" for "builder".
```

Me interesaría saber a que se debe.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás usando `this.` para llamar a builder? Creo que ese warning es porque estás accedediendo como si fuera un método de la instancia (`this.builder()`) en lugar de un método estático (`GenericResponse.builder()`)

Comment: al llamar el builder desde una capa de servicio no tengo el warning, y al intentar usar el ( ```this.builder()``` ) dentro del metodo ( ```crear()``` ) me fuerza a devolverlo a ( ```Child.builder()``` )

Comment: `SuperBuilder` es una característica experimental de `Lombok`, por lo tanto `SonarLint` puede dar falsos positivos. Yo descartaría el warning. Ver https://community.sonarsource.com/t/false-positive-on-missing-constructor-for-classes-with-lombok-s-builder-annotation/55558